# How to force delete dataproc serverless batch

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

I am running a pyspark dataproc serverless batch. It has been running for too long so I decided to delete it. But neither the GCP console nor the CLI allow me to delete the batch.

The command I tried is

```bash
gcloud dataproc batches delete <Batch ID> --region=us-central1
```

I get the following error:

> `ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.batches.delete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Cannot delete non terminal batch 'Batch(<project-id/batch-id>)'; current state: 'RUNNING'`

Comment: I think you want to try `gcloud dataproc batches cancel`

Comment: Perfect, this cancelled the batch immediately.  Thanks @Dagang!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcloud dataproc batches cancel` is used to cancel a running batch, while `gcloud dataproc batches delete` is used to delete the batch resource. In this case, you want to use `cancel`.